# Transformar "5,5" String a Float "5.5"

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy trabajando con `pytesseract` y debe reconocer una imagen la cual tiene un número decimal pero separado por "," en vez de ".".

¿Existe alguna forma de reemplazar la coma en el `string` por un punto para luego poder convertirlo en un float sin ningún problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amigo, puedes probar con el siguiente código dónde se utiliza `.replace`:
El método `replace ()` reemplaza una frase especificada con otra frase especificada.

```
num = "5,5"    
x = num.replace(",", ".")    
print(x)
#De esta manera puedes convertir "5.5" en Float.
varFloat=float(x)
print type(varFloat)
```

Espero haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: Genial! muchas gracias me fue de muchísima ayuda mi amigo.

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta, dónde se incluye la manera de convertir la variable de String a Float, siempre es un gusto ayuda. ¡Feliz decodificación!